# What is the most efficient way to group by day for overlapping date ranges (SQL Server 2008)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

Consider a simplified table T1 as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 (
    id        INTEGER       NOT NULL
    ,measure  NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL
    ,begin_dt DATE          NOT NULL
    ,end_dt   DATE          NOT NULL
);
```

Assume that constraints / business logic ensure that while each id can have multiple records, there are no overlapping date ranges for a single id and no date range gaps for a single id. e.g.,

```
id   | measure |  begin_dt  |   end_dt
-----------------------------------------
1    |  100.00 | 2012-05-07 | 2012-05-30
1    |  200.00 | 2012-05-31 | 2013-10-11
1    |   50.00 | 2013-10-12 | 2013-10-13
1    |    0.00 | 2013-10-14 | 9999-12-31
2    | 1234.56 | 2002-02-25 | 9999-12-31
3    |    9.87 | 2014-01-31 | 2014-02-15
3    |   50.00 | 2014-02-16 | 2015-01-04
3    |    0.00 | 2015-01-05 | 9999-12-31
...
```

Now, my goal is to produce a resultset that shows one record for every unique begin_dt in T1, along with the count of id's with positive measure value and the sum of the measure field across all id's for which that date falls between the begin_dt and end_dt. So, something like the following:

```
    dt     | count_of_ids | sum_of_measure 
-------------------------------------------
2002-02-25 |      1       |   1234.56 
2012-05-07 |      2       |   1334.56 
2012-05-31 |      2       |   1434.56 
2013-10-12 |      2       |   1284.56 
2013-10-14 |      1       |   1234.56 
2014-01-31 |      2       |   1244.43 
2014-02-16 |      2       |   1284.56
2015-01-05 |      1       |   1234.56
...
```

My current solution is essentially the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.begin_dt AS dt
    FROM dbo.T1 AS t1
) AS dt_s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(t1.id)     AS count_of_ids
           ,SUM(t1.measure) AS sum_of_measure
    FROM dbo.T1 AS t1
    WHERE t1.measure > 0
          AND dt_s.dt BETWEEN t1.begin_dt AND t1.end_dt
) AS t1_x
ORDER BY dt_s.dt DESC;
```

This takes roughly 3.5 minutes to execute (on the actual dataset with ~10MM records, ~2,500 unique dates and many more fields, measures, & aggregations to deal with) - I'm hoping there's a way to get that < 10 seconds or so.

I've attempted other approaches (using UDFs / CTEs / etc.), but they all seem to follow the same execution plan. I don't have much experience with the optimization side of things yet, so I'm eager to hear from others what the best general approach to this would be. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have index on your table?

Comment: Do you have a _single_ index consisting of `begin_dt`, `measure` (descending) and including `id`? (That would be a [covering index](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/). Note that SQL Server 2005 and later versions support [included columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) as well as composite indexes.)

Comment: I initially had a single non-clustered index on begin_dt, end_dt and including id. I altered the table to have the specs that @HABO suggested, and the new result is about a 5 min execution time (with 370,337,292 logical reads vs the previous 214,776,120 logical reads when setting statistics io on).

Comment: How about an index on: `begin_dt`, `end_dt`, `measure` (descending) and including `id`. I failed to take the `between` dates into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
SELECT  t1.begin_dt AS dt,COUNT(t2.id) AS count_of_ids,SUM(t1.measure) AS sum_of_measure
    FROM dbo.T1 AS t1
    JOIN dbo.T1 AS t2 ON t1.begin_dt BETWEEN t2.begin_dt AND t2.end_dt
    GROUP BY t1.begin_dt;
```

Performance can definitely be improved by making use of index on begin_dt, end_dt with convering fields ID and measure.
Hope this helps!